# Sending a program change with a program number (patch number)

Tags: audiokit

I have two Roland midi devices that behave the same when I try to send a bank and program change.  It always sets it to the first patch of the bank. It won't change the patch I choose in the bank.  Pro Logic can, however, switch to different banks.

The following example cause the devices to change to the bank but the program (patch) on the device defaults to the first in that bank and not number 9.

```
var event = AKMIDIEvent(controllerChange: 0, value: 89, channel: 0)
midiOut.sendEvent(event)
event = AKMIDIEvent(controllerChange: 32, value: 64, channel: 0)
midiOut.sendEvent(event)
event = AKMIDIEvent(programChange: 9, channel: 0)
midiOut.sendEvent(event)
```

Anyone have experience with sending this MIDI messages?

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same issue and was about to go crazy. It turns out the Program Change values in various MIDI data specifications, from various vendors, are 1 based. Not 0. Or perhaps it is the AudioKit implementation that is wrong?

So, instead of a programChange value of 9 you should use a value of 8. Here is my code for changing the current instrument on channel 0 to the Bösendorfer grand piano on a Yamaha Clavinova keyboard, where the programChange value in the MIDI data specification is designated as 1.

```
midiOut.sendControllerMessage(0, value: 108) // MSB sound bank selection
midiOut.sendControllerMessage(32, value: 0) // LSB sound bank selection
midiOut.sendEvent(AKMIDIEvent(programChange: 0, channel: 0)) // Initiate program change based on MSB and LSB selections
```

While reading various documentation about how MIDI works I also saw some forum posts describing keyboards that expect the LSB bank selection before the MSB bank selection. That is however not my understanding of how MIDI should work, but worth a try if you still cannot make it work with your Roland keyboards.